# R ecdet in ca.jo()

Tags: r, cointegration

I am experimenting with the `ca.jo` function of the `urca` package and I am getting confused about the `ecdet` argument. In the documentation it is mentioned that `ecdet` has three possible values: `none` for no intercept in cointegration, `const` for constant term in cointegration and `trend` for trend variable in cointegration. I have three questions.

1. Does "in cointegration" mean "in the error correction term"? In the `urca` document it seems as if the deterministic terms were outside the error correction term.
2. When I run the trace test with `ecdet = "none"`, the printout says `Test type: trace statistic , with linear trend`. Why?
3. When I use `ecdet = "trend"`, the printout says `Test type: trace statistic, with linear trend in cointegration`. Constant and linear trend, or linear trend through the origin?

Comment: I do not think that "This question appears to be off-topic because it focuses on programming, debugging, or performing routine operations, or it asks about obtaining datasets" is correct. I can use the ca.jo function, I just don't understand the printout. Most importantly, if ecdet = none, why does the printout talk about linear trend?

Comment: Have you tried reading the documentation carefully? If that did not help, have you considered asking this on an appropriate R mailing list and/or contacting the author(s) of the R package? (I did not vote for closing the question.)

Comment: Yes, I read the documentation and searched the internet, but failed to find an answer. It might be my fault, but I still find it strange. And whoever voted for closing this question, he/she could have answered it with the same effort.

Comment: If it were so easy to answer, it probably would have been answered before closing.

Comment: If it is not that easy, then why is it so terrible to ask the community? I though that this would be one of the purposes of a blog like this.

Comment: First, this is not a blog. Second, it has a well defined scope. Your question appeared to be outside of it. Third, no one (aside from you) said it was terrible to ask.

Comment: On my screen, under Related", I can see "Why does ca.jo has a minimum lag order of 2?" Is this question really so different from mine that it can be answered on this 'site', but mine not?

Comment: Your questions seems to be *entirely* about software (no statistical content), while the other one asks for a *statistical* reason for a particular design of the software.